# docker-ce 17.06.0-ce failed to pull from private registry mirror

Tags: docker

After I upgrade docker-ce to latest 17.06.0-ce, I can not pull from my private registry...

before upgrade, I can docker pull tae/uc, which is my private image on my private registry, which is configured in /etc/docker/daemon.json

{   "registry-mirrors": ["https://admin:password@registry.local:5005"] }

after upgrade, I failed to pull without specifying the registry...

The only way I can pull is like docker pull registry.local:5005/tae/uc,
which is very annoying.

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the error on pulling without specifying the repository?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your registry is only providing registry API v1 and [Docker-ce 17.06 dropped support of it](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/#17060-ce-2017-06-28):

> Deprecation
>
> > Disable legacy registry (v1) by default [#33629](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/33629)

Upgrade your registry or try to re-enable legacy registry by adding `"disable-legacy-registry": false` in your `daemon.json`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, zigarn.  This is not my case. I'm using v2 registry.  And I tried to add this option to daemon.json , but didn't work.

Comment: Is there any message about your 'registry-mirror' in your docker daemon logs ?

Comment: journal logs keeps complaining as below, but I'm pretty I've docker logged in and the mirror-registry has the username/password as the basic auth header. 

level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"

level=info msg="Ignoring extra error returned from registry: unauthorized: authentication required"

level=info msg="Translating \"denied: requested access to the resource is denied\" to \"repository tae/uc not found: does not exist or no pull access\""

Comment: yes, there was an error in the nexus docker registry.

2017-07-06 05:05:55,658-0400 WARN  [qtp746235617-150197] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: HEAD /v2/tae/uc/blobs/sha256:0576129d6a99d6ff6b5b7f2a53374f45d326d1aa2de653f832c58b1b9c4c3322: 404 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception$BlobNotFound: blob unknown to registry